# Adding an html page to a web app

Tags: web-applications, google-apps-script

I'm pretty new in programming, mostly doing it for fun, so sorry if the question is too obvious and appreciate if you could answer as if I know very little...
:)

So I'm trying to make a web app using Google Apps Script, but I wanna design it in Dreamweaver first and use that html for the app (Since the "Build A UI" option is no longer exist in Google Scripts).
The app needs to be able to read and modify the original html, in response to the user's actions.

I was thinking to simply do this, but it didn't work, of course:

```
function doGet(e) {
var app = UiApp.createApplication();
var page = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('MyHtml');
app.add(page);
return app;
}
```

It **does** work when I write `return page;` but I just can't reach the fields later, in other functions, when I use `var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();`

**================================= EDIT =================================**

Here's an example for why I need the web app to contain the html page:

```
function showMyEmail() {
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

// Assuming 'email_lbl' is the ID of the already existing target label I want to modify.
app.getElementById('email_lbl').setText('Your email is: ' + email);
return app;
}
```

Unfortunately I can't use it like that because "app" doesn't contain any object that's called "email_lbl".
So I need to find a way to embed the html file in the app so I can later on use the `UiApp.getActiveApplication();` in other server-side functions.

Also - my first example obviously returned a blank page because "app" didn't contain the "page". (Same problem of course...)

**================================= EDIT =================================**

Any suggestions? Creative work-arounds? Something I'm missing here?

Sorry if I'm being redundant. I don't know how to explain better...

Appreciate your attention!!
iyar

Comment: If you need to send data from your Web App to server side code (in a .gs file) you will need to use the `google.script.run.functionName()` client side API.  [Link to Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)  If you are not familiar with that, take a quick look at it.  I guarantee that you will need to use it.  If that doesn't help you, comment back.

Comment: Hi Sandy,
Thanks for responding!

I'm familiar with this method but my problem starts even before the user is even doing anything.
"app" doesn't contain "page" and therefore the page is blank. I need to find a way to embed the html page in the web app so it will be shown and also for further use in server-side functions.

I've edited my question above to shows an example of such use.

Answer (score 1):

You would return the HtmlService itself as you pointed out. All you client side logic would be handled by your Html page as Apps Scripts run on server side. So any JavaScript that requires access to `document` or `window` needs to be in your html page. Since it is a webapp you have access to `google.script.run` to run code in your script.

Check out its docs for this and webapps at:

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run
>   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

code.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  var page = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('MyHtml');
  return page;
}

function square(val){
  return val*val
}
```

MyHtml.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>    
    <p id="val"></p>
  </body>
  <script>
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showVal).square(5);  

    function showVal(returnVal){
      document.getElementById('val').textContent = returnVal
    }
  </script>
</html>
```